# How to prevent Android Studio from recognizing strings.xml as plain text

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, I created a project with one module `app`, which has two flavors: vanilla (regular app) + dogfood (for internal use) and the two default build variants `debug` and `release`.

The tree structure looks like this (left out build and gradle folders):

```
/myawesomeproject
 - app
    - src
        - dogfoodDebug
        - dogfoodRelease
        - main
        - vanillaDebug
        - vanillaRelease
```

Each subfolder of `src` has a `res/values` and `res/values-nl`resource folders, where both contain a `strings.xml` file.

Silly enough, Android Studio does not want to recognize it as a Android Resource file. It appears in the list as a plain text file. This is really inconvenient, as everywhere in lay-out and code files, each string is only recognized after I build the project again.

I already...

- [found](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/04/exclude-single-file/) the `Right click on the file > Mark file as ...`, but that option is just not shown in the context menu.
- renamed one of the `strings.xml` to `strings2.xml`. After that, the file was recognized as an Android Resource file.

Now, the latter thing could solve it, but I think it is very silly that I should rename a file to have it correctly recognized by an IDE.

Comment: In Android Studio, only one flavor + build type combination will be active at once, so in non-active variants, you won't get first-class treatment of source files.

Comment: Is it possible this is a windows box, and windows stupidly stuck a .txt at the end of your xml file's name?

Comment: @ScottBarta True, but other resource files than strings.xml are still always recognized as Android Resource files.

Comment: @StuartSiegler I'm indeed on a Windows environment. Unfortunately, what you suggest is not the case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio not identifying xml file as layout file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160834/android-studio-not-identifying-xml-file-as-layout-file)