# Android Studio not identifying xml file as layout file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, intellij-idea

I accidentally created `drawer_list_item.xml` in the screenshot using `New -> File` menu, instead of `New -> Layout resource file` and now I can't open it as a regular layout file in design mode. It opens it as a plain text file.

[image]

Is there any way I can change its type. I couldn't find anything related to this through Android Studio's settings

File content:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

              <TextView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Edit for more things I tried:

- recreating does not work, as it creates it the same way. But, when I recreate it after deletion it gives the following exception. I close the window and the old text file re-appears

  ```
          null
  java.lang.AssertionError
  at org.jetbrains.android.util.AndroidResourceUtil.createFileResource(AndroidResourceUtil.java:1251)
  at org.jetbrains.android.actions.CreateTypedResourceFileAction.doCreateAndNavigate(CreateTypedResourceFileAction.java:131)
  at org.jetbrains.android.actions.CreateMultiRootResourceFileAction.create(CreateMultiRootResourceFileAction.java:108)
  at org.jetbrains.android.actions.CreateResourceActionBase$MyInputValidator.create(CreateResourceActionBase.java:292)
  at com.intellij.ide.actions.ElementCreator$1.run(ElementCreator.java:73)
  at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
  at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:114)
  at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1010)
  at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2.run(WriteCommandAction.java:111)
  at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:124)
  at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
  at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:108)
  at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:80)
  at com.intellij.ide.actions.ElementCreator.tryCreate(ElementCreator.java:92)
  at org.jetbrains.android.actions.CreateResourceActionBase$MyInputValidator.canClose(CreateResourceActionBase.java:302)
  at org.jetbrains.android.actions.CreateMultiRootResourceFileAction$MyDialog.doOKAction(CreateMultiRootResourceFileAction.java:174)
  at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$OkAction.doAction(DialogWrapper.java:1833)
  at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1799)
  at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
  at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
  at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
  at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
  at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
  at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
  at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
  at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
  at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
  at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
  at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
  at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
  at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
  at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
  at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
  at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
  at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
  at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
  at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
  at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:792)
  at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:465)
  at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1638)
  at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1587)
  at org.jetbrains.android.actions.CreateMultiRootResourceFileAction.invokeDialog(CreateMultiRootResourceFileAction.java:80)
  at org.jetbrains.android.actions.CreateResourceActionBase.actionPerformed(CreateResourceActionBase.java:183)
  at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:182)
  at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:311)
  at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:958)
  at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
  at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:281)
  at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
  at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:109)
  at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
  at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
  at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
  at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
  at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
  at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
  at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
  at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
  at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
  at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
  at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
  at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
  at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
  ```
- if I rename the file to drawer_item.xml, it gains the icon and is seen as a layout file. If I rename it back to drawer_list_item.xml, the problem returns. So it probably indexed it somewhere as a plain text file...
- invalidate caches / restart does not fix the problem
- Tried renaming `.idea/workspakce.xml` to `.idea/workspace.xml.bk` so it recreates it in case I missed something - still no luck. I even tried removing `.idea` folder and `app.iml` file from the root folder, but no fix

Comment: Why not just delete and remake it

Comment: I tried that, but it creates it in the same way

Comment: Did you do `New -> Layout resource file` the second time?

Comment: What do you have in drawer_list_item.xml?

Comment: just copy the content and make it a layout resource file this time and paste the content and you are good to go

Comment: It is curious to me because AS should recognize the .xml file as a layout file and show the xml icon (like in your activity_details.xml). I just tried making test.xml using new->file and it gives me the correct .xml icon. Maybe try restarting AS

Comment: @cricket_007, yes, but it gives `Cannot create file '.../src/main/res/layout/drawer_list_item.xml'. File already exists.` I click on and then it reappears in the list as in the screenshot

Comment: Hit shift twice and search for the other instance of drawer_list_item.xml

Comment: @EricS. it contains a `LinearLayout` with a `TextView` in it, nothing special

Comment: post the xml contents

Comment: nothing at double shift after delete. at recreate the error with the file already exists. adding content to initial post

Comment: Something is out of sync, I recommend  `file->invalidating caches and restart.`

Comment: not working. If i recreate the file using `New -> Layout resource file` it creates it with the content of a new layout file (e.g.: containing only a `LinearLayout`), but sees it as plain text. It's like when you right click on a layout file and choose `Mark as plain text`. Also, if I rename the file to `drawer_item.xml`, it gains the icon and is seen as a layout file. If I rename it back to `drawer_list_item.xml`, the problem returns. So it probably indexed it somewhere as a plain text file...

Comment: Check the IntelliJ project workspace file for an entry matching the name of your XML file.  So look at the `.idea/workspace.xml` file in an editor (not in AS itself - in fact, I recommend exiting AS while you do this.)  The file should have an `<entry file...>` type tag and in that tag will be a sub-tag `provider`.  Check that the `editor-type-id` is set to `"android-designer"`.

Comment: This doesn't fix it either it seems. I found it in the file with `editor-type-id="text-editor">`, changed it to `android-designer` - no luck. Tried renaming `workspakce.xml` to `workspace.xml.bk` so it recreates it in case I missed something - still no luck. I even tried removing .idea and app.iml from the folder and nothing solves

Comment: Ok, kinda found the root of the problem. I renamed ~/.AndroidStudioPreview2.0 (the settings directory in my home directory) so it recreates it and the problem is gone. Why would it keep data about my project there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the source of the problem - it was in the config files Android Studio creates in your home directory: `~/.AndroidStudioPreview2.0`. In my case, it was `~/.AndroidStudioPreview2.0/config/options/filetypes.xml`

```
    <application>
      <component name="FileTypeManager" version="16">
        <ignoreFiles list="*.hprof;*.pyc;*.pyo;*.rbc;*~;.DS_Store;.git;.hg;.svn;CVS;RCS;SCCS;__pycache__;_svn;rcs;" />
        <extensionMap>
          <mapping pattern="drawer_list_item.xml" type="PLAIN_TEXT" />
        </extensionMap>
      </component>
    </application>
```

Therefore, it seems like I somehow made Android Studio index that file name pattern `drawer_list_item.xml` as plain text...
Removing that mapping entry from the file solves the problem: `<mapping pattern="drawer_list_item.xml" type="PLAIN_TEXT" />`

Comment: On my computer, the location of `filetypes.xml` is `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioX.X/options/filetypes.xml`

Answer (score 11):

`Preferences -> File Types` and remove the `Registered Pattern`[image: Android Studio Preferences]

Comment: I could not find it in text. So what helped me, to try to add the full name to XML and so I got the warning containing where the file name is stored. In my case it was auto detect file type by content

Answer (score 2):

I simply had to right click on the file in the Project view and select 'Mark as XML' in Android Studio 2.2.x

[image]

Comment: Sadly I have no "Mark as XML" at that location.

Answer (score 2):

It happens sometimes when wrong indexes/caches are created by Android Studio.

1. Go to **File** menu
2. Click on **Invalidate Caches / Restart**
3. Restart your IDE and wait for IDE to reindex the files

It should be okay after doing those ...

Comment: thats very inconvenient if I have to restart Android Studio every time I add a new resource file

Comment: @lollerskates If you want, you can report this bug to Jet-Brains company

Comment: unfortunately it still doesnt recognize the file even after invalidate caches and restart

Comment: @LenaBru try other answers first, if they didn't work, close the project in android studio completely from the File menu, then move to .idea folder which is inside your main project folder and remove it, then open your project again from the File menu, Open. Your android studio regenerate a fresh .idea folder and the project cache refreshes! hope this help

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue because of `importandroid.R` in one of the activity file. Just removed it and it is all good now.