# Android Studio xml layout files not recognized as layout file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I've been encountering some very odd problems with Android Studio today.

When I open an XML layout file, it opens as a plain text for some reason. It even says that I have a typo for `constraintLayout` and tells me to change it to `constraint's layout`.

There's no design view choice in sight.

I tried adding elements by hand in the XML file but, when I type in `Text` usually the TextView property should appear for me to choose. However, that doesn't show up lol.

I tried invalidating caches, rebuilding my project, cleaning my project, restarting my laptop, and this method: [Android Studio not identifying xml file as layout file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160834/android-studio-not-identifying-xml-file-as-layout-file) but they all don't work for some reason.

Usually my layout files should have a small icon thing in the file structure thing but that also doesn't show up.

Thanks so much.

Edit: here's what it looks like in my XML file
[image]

What the icon looks like:
[image]

I also tried just adding things to my XML by hand and running it on my device. The thing does run, and my textView shows up on my screen, but when I try to use `findViewById` to find it in my activity file, it can't find the id.

Comment: Pls describe with xml, it will make easier to solve the issue

Comment: I think you mistakenly have removed .xml extension. Please check and try to add .xml extension to the file name or create a new layout resource and try to use it.

Comment: @Nitesh i have attached some pictures that I hope will explain things better. As you can see, the .XML extension is not lost. Whatever new layout resource files I make have the same problem.

Comment: have you tried other projects? to limit whether its a project problem or an android studio problem. Also, are your layouts going to the right directory when you create them, in the 'res/layout'?

Comment: Try Invalidate cache and restart .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on `activity_login.xml` file from Project/android view structure and select `Mark as XML` . Somehow this file marked as text file from your IDE.

Comment: Right click on layout file -> Override file type -> now selectect XML

Answer (score 0):

can you check that `activity_login.xml` is in the correct directory `res/layout`? I found the same issue, I resolved the issue by clearing caches in `Android Studio`. Follow Steps to Clear Caches
Go to  `File > menu > Invalidate Caches > select option invalidate` and restart `Android Studio`.